# Ajax forms not working in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: mvc, ajax

We have deployed the code files to a fresh `9.3 XP instance` and the `Ajax form` renders differently.

**View:**

```
using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm(MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, null, 
new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "fn_MemberRegistration" }, 
new { id = "form-email-verification", data_step = 1 }))
{
}
```

**In the 8.2 instances it renders as:**

```
<form action="/sign-up" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" 
data-ajax-success="fn_MemberRegistration" data-step="1" id="form-email-verification" 
method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

**But in 9.3, it renders as:**

```
<form action="/sign-up" data-step="1" id="form-email-verification" method="post" 
onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));" 
onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { 
insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, httpMethod: 'Post', 
onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, fn_MemberRegistration) });">
```

In `web.config`, we already have these settings:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
```

**Versions in use:**
`Mvc - 5.2.4`
`jQuery - 3.4.1.min.js`

**UPDATE:**
@x3mxray suggestion helped me resolve this.
The issue was with the `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` setting. There was a duplicate set to false that was overwriting the previous. Removing the duplicate fixed the issue.

Comment: It means that somehow unobtrusive is disabled (and MicrosoftAjax is used instead). Make sure that UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled is true (does not overwritten by duplicated appsetting). I just checked it on my clear 9.3 solution: Without UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=true it looks like in your case, but when I only add one appsetting UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=true - it looks good (with data-attributes), I even didn`t include any scripts, just a clear page with only one Ajax.BeginRouteForm. Check your web.config